# llenar un Select desde Mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

creo que estoy un poco verde combinando PHP y HTML.
el tema es el siguiente..
Tengo esto en PHP que funciona correctamente:

```
<?php
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root") or
die("Problemas en la conexion");
mysql_select_db("ad6138",$conexion) or
die("Problemas en la selección de la base de datos");  
$clavebuscadah=mysql_query("select Codigo,NObra,Descripcion from obra ",$conexion) or
die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
echo "<select name='select1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clavebuscadah))
{
echo'<OPTION VALUE="'.$row['Codigo'].'">'.$row['NObra'].'</OPTION>';

}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

ahora trato de incluirlo en un HTML y .......'Desastre total'...

```
<body>
<?php
$conexion=mysql_connect("localhost","root") or
die("Problemas en la conexion");
mysql_select_db("ad6138",$conexion) or
die("Problemas en la selección de la base de datos");  
$clavebuscadah=mysql_query("select Codigo,NObra,Descripcion from obra ",$conexion) or
die("Problemas en el select:".mysql_error());
echo "<select name='select1'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($clavebuscadah))
{
echo'<OPTION VALUE="'.$row['Codigo'].'">'.$row['NObra'].'</OPTION>';

}
echo "</select>";
?>

<input type="submit" id="Button1" onclick="window.location.href='./identificación.html';return false;" name="" 

value="Siguiente >" style="position:absolute;left:374px;top:387px;width:222px;height:47px;z-index:1;">
<label for="" id="Label1" style="position:absolute;left:275px;top:9px;width:438px;height:29px;line-height:29px;z-

index:2;">ELEGIR ORDEN DE TRABAJO</label>
</body>
```

A ver si alguien me puede orientar..
Gracias...

Comment: Deberás editar y mostrar que error te aparece, por que decir **Desastre total** no da mucha idea de lo que ocurre

Comment: No aparace error alguno, simplemente que en el HTML el select no se llena con los datos de la BD. y en el PHP Si lo hace....

Comment: No entiendo mucho eso de que el HTML no y en el PHP si, pero aquí practicando mis dotes adivinescos, sera estas guardando en extensión .html? de ser si, php no corre en extensión .html php en .php

Comment: el primer código es un archivo PHP, funciona correctamente, crea un desplegable con los datos que extrae de la BD.

Comment: El archivo donde tratas de mostrar el select tiene extensión .php?

Comment: Cierto, es la extension del archivo.... Gracias a todos....

Answer (score 1):

Recuerda que el archivo donde estas usando HTML también debe ser de extensión `.php`

> Si me permites, te recomiendo que utilices *mysqli*, en lugar de *mysql* ya que *mysqli* es la extensión de *mysql* mejorada y por lo tanto es la más óptima.

- [Extensión `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Recuerda no es solo que sea la versión mas óptima, sino que además la extensión *mysql* esta obsoleta